# Beating the snake boss in Magicka

Tags: magicka

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I defeat Jormungandr, the snake/worm boss at the end of Chapter 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15624/how-do-i-defeat-jormungandr-the-snake-worm-boss-at-the-end-of-chapter-2)

Recently started playing Magicka and I've just started fighting "the snake boss"(2nd boss). Hes giving me a real tough time to be honest. Is there something specifically that needs to be done?

I've been treating it as a standard boss battle and searching for a decent opening to hit him. However the best opening I can find(Hit him in the face when he roars) always results in us trading blows. I'm pretty sure I could win eventually but I'm wondering if theres a better way.

I've tried freezing him with water followed up with ice, beam attacks and fire balls. Or am I over complicating it when I should just slog away and spam heals?